# @google-pay/button-angular issue: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pay'),

Tags: angular, angular6, integration, element, google-pay

For the Google pay payments in my application, I was using @google-pay/button-angular in angular

The HTML code is:
<google-pay - button[environment]="current_env"[buttonColor] = "buttonColor"[buttonType] = "buttonType"

[buttonSizeMode] = "isCustomSize ? 'fill' : 'static'"[paymentRequest] = "paymentRequest"

(loadpaymentdata) = "onLoadPaymentData($event)" >

In TS file the code was,

current_env: String = environment.production != true ? "TEST" : "PRODUCTION";

buttonColor: String = "black";

buttonType: String = "pay";

isCustomSize = false;

Earlier it was working fine.

Today I observed that Google Pay button is showing for the element. The error is attached.[image]

Answer (score 0):

While fixing, I found that 'pay' is not working in 'buttonType' option. So, I changed it to

buttonType: String = "short";

Now it is working fine, for more details, please refer https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-pay/button-angular

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple types not working on Google's own [implementation docs](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/resources/customize) so I assume this is a Google bug.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).